# Module ImportError in JMeter

Tags: python, jmeter, jython

I want to use JMETER to run python scripts, compile my python scripts with Jython, but show importError requsets, I don't know how to install this modules (package) in Jmeter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noLCi.jpg)

[JSR223 description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAFbZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [Jython](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html)
2. Install [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module like:

   ```
   \\location\\of\\jython\\jython -m pip install requests
   ```
3. Add the following line to the beginning of your script in the JSR223 Sampler:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append('\\location\\of\\jython\\site-packages')
   ```

However the above approach is more like a "workaround":

- if you plan to run the Python code for higher loads - it makes sense to re-write it in [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) as JMeter will be loading a 35MB beast into memory in order to launch Python interpreter each time JSR223 Sampler will be called
- if you don't plan to run the Python code for high loads - it will be much easier to use underlying Python installation in the operating system and call the Python interpreter using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you need to add jython standalone jar in lib folder of jmeter:

- http://www.jython.org/downloads.html

If issue still persists, show your JSR223 Sampler.

Comment: I have added the jython standalone jar and used the JSR223 Sampler, but jython itself does not have a requests module.